# How to change audio with subprocess?

Tags: python

I want to make a music player with tkkinter that plays .wav files. I created everything, but a volume slider. I created the volume slider but I wanted to know how to change the volume in sub process. I tried this code :

```
from subprocess import call
call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "0%"])
```

When I ran it I got the following error : "Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/Parent/Desktop/Python/volume chang.py", line 2, in <module>
    call(["harvard.wav", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "0%"])
  File "C:\Users\Parent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Parent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Parent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
"
```

I wanted to know if I could fix this and be able to change volume.

Comment: The second line in your code sample doesn't match the Traceback message.

Comment: whoops, i forgot to copy the code from that program.

Comment: The code is here : "from subprocess import call
call(["harvard.wav", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "0%"])"

Comment: A wav file (or its associated program respectively) can't be executed this way. Either call the associated program or use the Windows shell command "start" to do that.

Comment: Do you know how to change the system volume then?